# Menubutton that updates depending on the selection in the menu in python + tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I get the menubutton text to update according to my selection in the menu? If I select opt1 I would like that the menubutton text updated to "opt1" after releasing/exiting the menu. Below is a simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def opt1():
    print "opt 1 selected "
    return;
def opt2():
    print "opt 2 selected "
    return;
def opt3():
    print "opt 3 selected "
    return;

elementTypeBtn = Menubutton(root, relief='raised', text='select sth')
elementTypeBtn.grid(row=0, column=0)
elementTypeBtn.menu = Menu(elementTypeBtn)
elementTypeBtn.menu.add_command(label='opt1', underline=0, command=opt1)
elementTypeBtn.menu.add_command(label='opt2', underline=0, command=opt2)
elementTypeBtn.menu.add_command(label='opt3', underline=0, command=opt3)
elementTypeBtn['menu'] = elementTypeBtn.menu

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to how you update any attribute of any widget, you call the [config](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#setting-options) (or `configure`) method that is common to all widgets:

```
def opt1():
    elementTypeBtn.configure(text="opt 1 selected")
    return;
```

Comment: ah, thx for the quick response to a python/tkinter-newb :) That solved it.